# Is this an alternative to the walking 1's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, testing, bit-manipulation

Ok, this is a long one, so please bear with me. The question is in the last paragraph.

My application reads boolean data from 100+ discrete inputs and packs them into a bunch of integers, which are later output over serial. I'm in the testing phase of development, and need to check that each input gets placed into the correct bit of the output. My first instinct was to use the walking 1's algorithm. This would generate several hundred test cases though, which takes time and effort to create, maintain, review, etc. So I've been encouraged to reduce the number of tests to what I feel comfortable with, even if it means some cases wouldn't get covered (presumably they'd be covered by tests by other teams). I don't feel comfortable not thoroughly testing my code, but I recognize the desire to reduce the number of test cases if possible. The walking 1's test would produce N test cases, where N is the number of inputs.

After thinking about it for a while, I came up with the following 3 tests. If any one of them fail, there is something wrong with the input conversion.

1. **Odds test** - Set every odd input to "on", yielding an alternating bit pattern in the output.
2. **Evens test** - Set every even input to "on", yielding an alternating bit pattern in the output.
3. **Walking 3's test** - This is my own name for the test, due to its similarity to the walking 1's test. Set the first two inputs to "on". Then set the next two inputs to "on", and so on, until there are 0 or 1 inputs left.

For each test, the output is compared to the input to see if it matches. If they don't match, XOR can be used to get the erroneous bits.

The idea is that the odds and even tests prove that the bits are independent of their neighboring bits. If 10101 is the input (odds test), an output of 10101 indicates that the even bits are not set (are independent of the odd bits) when an odd bit is set. Same goes for the even bits. That reduces the set of possible dependent bits by half. Then by testing the 3's, we can prove independence of the rest of the bits. For example, if input is 00011 and output is 00011, we know from the odds/evens test that bit 1 is independent of bit 0, and now we know from the 3's test that bits 0 and 1 are independent of the rest of the bits, otherwise at least one of those bits would be 1. Continuing the example, if input 00011 gives us 00111 for output, we know via XOR that bit 2 is dependent on bit 0 (remember that the evens and odds test passed, so bit 0 is the only possible source of dependence). Or if input 00011 gives us 00110 for output, we know again via XOR that once again bits 0 and 2 are the problem (in this case, they appear to be swapped).

An example of this for a 5-bit sequence is below (in my application it's actually a series of 19-bit sequences). These examples consider the case where two bits are swapped. Bits that are stuck on or off can be detected solely by the odd and even tests.

Compared to the walking 1's test, these 3 tests yield `floor(N/2) + 2` test cases. But do these make a valid replacement for the walking 1's test? My example seems to indicate so (at least for my purposes), but I'm not sure. I would've expected to see this technique elsewhere, but I haven't found it. Of course, I don't know what name I should be looking for.

```
Swap bits 0 and 1
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 10110  | Yes       |
| 01010 | evens   | 01001  | Yes       |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 00011  | No        |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 01100  | No        |


Swap bits 0 and 2
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 10101  | No        |
| 01010 | evens   | 01010  | No        |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 00110  | Yes       |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 01100  | No        |


Swap bits 0 and 3
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 11100  | Yes       |
| 01010 | evens   | 00011  | Yes       |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 01010  | Yes       |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 00101  | Yes       |


Swap bits 0 and 4
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 10101  | No        |
| 01010 | evens   | 01010  | No        |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 10010  | Yes       |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 01100  | No        |


Swap bits 1 and 2
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 10011  | Yes       |
| 01010 | evens   | 01100  | Yes       |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 00101  | Yes       |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 01010  | Yes       |


Swap bits 1 and 3
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 10101  | No        |
| 01010 | evens   | 01010  | No        |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 01001  | Yes       |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 00110  | Yes       |


Swap bits 1 and 4
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 00111  | Yes       |
| 01010 | evens   | 11000  | Yes       |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 10001  | Yes       |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 01100  | No        |


Swap bits 2 and 3
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 11001  | Yes       |
| 01010 | evens   | 00110  | Yes       |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 00011  | No        |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 01100  | No        |


Swap bits 2 and 4
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 10101  | No        |
| 01010 | evens   | 01010  | No        |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 00011  | No        |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 11000  | Yes       |


Swap bits 3 and 4
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 01101  | Yes       |
| 01010 | evens   | 10010  | Yes       |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 00011  | No        |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 10100  | Yes       |
```

Comment: What actually needs to be tested? And why N discrete test cases?

Comment: It depends on how you define "dependent". If bit x is dependent on bit y means the two bits always have the same value, then the tests look good. If dependent means they have some kind of logical relationship then maybe not because for e.g. bit 1 is always NOT bit 2 in the input

Comment: @user2864740 - What needs to be tested is that if I ground (turn on) one of the discrete inputs, its corresponding bit needs to be set in the output. N test cases, one for each input to the software.

Comment: @samgak - By dependent, I mean that if I turn on bit 0, and I get both bit 0 and 1 on in my output. There is no logical relationship between the inputs. It's basically just enumerating them. I read 24 inputs at a time from the hardware, but due to protocol overhead, can only output 19 bits. So I'm trying to test that I got my bit shifting correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `n` bits, you could use `ceil(log2(n + 2))` tests to detect permuted and stuck bits, where in test `i` (ranging from `0` to `ceil(log2(n + 2)) - 1`), the value of bit `j` (ranging from `1` to `n`) is the bit corresponding to `2**i` in the binary representation of `j`.

```
test 0: 10101010101010
test 1: 01100110011001
test 2: 00011110000111
test 3: 00000001111111
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow from the description alone. Could you give an example?

Comment: Does this technique have any commonly referred to name that I could use for reference purposes?

Comment: @njpaul There's a lot of prior art, but I'm not sure if there's a concise name for this technique.

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider what the plausible errors are, what determines the cost of an individual test, and sometimes how easy it will be to diagnose the underlying problem given a test failure. On some equipments a walking one test is very easy to input, because you can walk the 1 across by just clearing one switch and setting its neighbor, and very easy to check, because it produces a distinctive pattern on output. It checks for a lot of plausible mis-wirings and non-wirings. (and both walking 1s and walking 3s seem to require much the same number of switch movements)

If the most plausible error is some mistake in your packing code, then life is more complicated - a mistake like using + where you should have used & might show up only when enough inputs were set to cause overflow. You could try a small number of completely random input patterns, or look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing. The catch with this is that you then need to set the switches to apparently completely random patterns, which may be much more frustrating and error prone than simply walking 1 along them.

Before or as well as using more sophisticated tests you could see what support you can provide with displays or automatic alarms to make the life of the tester easier and less error-prone.

Comment: The most likely error is that there is a bug in my bit packing code, and that is what these test cases will try to check. The tests themselves will be automated and running in a simulated environment where there are no problems with the hardware (mis-wiring, etc.). The cost of an individual test isn't so much the runtime cost, as that is minimal, but the cost of producing the documentation, reviewing it, maintaining it, and releasing it.

Comment: If you can automate everything I would have at least one test that uses a random number generator to generate a random pattern, encodes it, decodes that, and checks that it gets back what it started with. Then I'd run it overnight.

Comment: That will make for a good robustness test case. For my normal tests, David's answer works with reasonable confidence.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, no this is not an alternative to walking 1's. Walking 1's can detect coupling between the bits. For instance, bit 4 also turns on bit 2, walking 1's will detect this. My algorithm would not detect this in all cases.

```
Walking 1's
Bit 4 also turns on bit 2
| Input | i | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---|--------|-----------|
| 00001 | 0 | 00001  | No        |
| 00010 | 1 | 00010  | No        |
| 00100 | 2 | 00100  | No        |
| 01000 | 3 | 01000  | No        |
| 10000 | 4 | 10100  | Yes       |


My algorithm
Bit 4 also turns on bit 2
| Input | Method  | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---------|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | odds    | 10101  | No        |
| 01010 | evens   | 01010  | No        |
| 00011 | 3's (1) | 00011  | No        |
| 01100 | 3's (2) | 01100  | No        |


David Eisenstat's algorithm
Bit 0 also turns on bit 2
| Input | i | Output | Detected? |
|-------|---|--------|-----------|
| 10101 | 0 | 10101  | No        |
| 00110 | 1 | 00110  | No        |
| 11000 | 2 | 11000  | No        |
```

So I guess it depends on what level of checking you need. If you need to check for coupled bits, walking 1's seems to be the way to go. If you only need to check for stuck bits and permutations, David Eisenstat's algorithm will do it more efficiently than mine.

In my case, I'm doing a lot of bit manipulation, and it's possible that I'd accidentally have 2 bits coupled, so I think it'll have to be walking 1's.

**EDIT**
Actually I decided to go with David Eisenstat's algorithm after more carefully examining the behavior of my application. In my application, if a bit manipulation is wrong, say bit 0 turns on bit 2, it would not also be possible for bit 2 to be turned on as intended, and the algorithm would detect that error.